# Adding a Rfcomm serial device to a Bluetooth adapter in Windows 10 with .Net

Tags: c#, .net, windows, sockets, bluetooth

I would like to use the Bluetooth serial port with .Net in Windows.

To open it, I try this:

```
var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(RfcommDeviceService.GetDeviceSelector(RfcommServiceId.SerialPort));
```

To be able to use this code, I've added the following to the [Package.appxmanifest](https://%3Cm2:DeviceCapability%20Name=%22bluetooth.rfcomm%22%3E) inside the `<Capabilities>` node:

```
<m2:DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth.rfcomm">
  <m2:Device Id="any">
    <m2:Function Type="name.serialPort"/>
  </m2:Device>
</m2:DeviceCapability>
```

Unfortunately, my Bluetooth adapter serial port will not be listed with this after a fresh installation of it inside the Windows `Device Manager`.

But after executing the [MyPhoneExplorer](https://www.fjsoft.at/) app, I get the `Rfcomm device` on the same way, named with "MyPhoneExplorer": [image: Screenshot]. But after uninstall / reinstall my Bluetooth Adapter inside the Windows device manager, it's gone again.

How can I add the `Rfcomm serial device` to my Bluetooth adapter, found with the follow code?

```
var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(RfcommDeviceService.GetDeviceSelector(RfcommServiceId.SerialPort));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the Rfcomm services can be used, they must be received from the remote Bluetooth device with this code:

```
var remoteDeviceInformations = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(BluetoothDevice.GetDeviceSelector());
foreach (var remoteDeviceInformation in remoteDeviceInformations)
{
    var remoteDevice = await BluetoothDevice.FromIdAsync(remoteDeviceInformation.Id);
    var rfcommServices = await remoteDevice.GetRfcommServicesForIdAsync(RfcommServiceId.SerialPort, BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached);
    if (rfcommServices.Error != BluetoothError.Success)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

With `GetRfcommServicesForIdAsync` the Rfcomm service will be built.